# Have error in WSO2 2.0.1 Android device registeration?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I installed a WSO2 2.0.1 server on ubuntu 14.04,then I want to register a android device and manage it.But after I scaned QR code with a android phone, it gave me a link

https://localhost:9443/emm-web-agent/enrollment

I cannot open this link on my phone .How can I configure WSO2 and change localhost to my server ip and then make it works?

Comment: Grammar correction

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the IP address in below configuration files.

- **[EMM_HOME]/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm/config.json**

Find,

```
"generalConfig" : {
        "host" : "https://localhost:9443",
        "companyName" : "WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager",
        "browserTitle" : "WSO2 EMM",
        "copyrightPrefix" : "\u00A9 %date-year%, ",
        "copyrightOwner" : "WSO2 Inc.",
        "copyrightOwnersSite" : "http://www.wso2.org",
        "copyrightSuffix" : ""
    }
```

Replace '*localhost*' in *"host" : "https://localhost:9443"* with your IP address

- **[EMM_HOME]/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/emm-web-agent**

Find,

```
"generalConfig" : {
        "host" : "http://localhost:9763",
        "companyName" : "WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager",
        "browserTitle" : "WSO2 EMM",
        "copyrightText" : "\u00A9 %date-year%, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights Reserved."
        }
```

Replace '*localhost*' in *"host" : "https://localhost:9763"* with your IP address